# SQL Server : export query as a .txt file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, export-to-text

I am trying to export my SQL Server query results into a folder in `.txt` format (this is for an automated job)

I know the equivalent in MySQL works with `INTO OUTFILE`. Does anyone know the best way to do this in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

```
SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM (s1.SGMNTID) AS 'AccCode',RTRIM (s1.DSCRIPTN) AS 'CodeDesc', CASE
    WHEN  s1.SGMTNUMB = '1' THEN '1' 
    WHEN s1.SGMTNUMB = '2' THEN '2'
    WHEN s1.SGMTNUMB = '3' THEN '110'
    WHEN s1.SGMTNUMB = '4' THEN '4'
    WHEN s1.SGMTNUMB = '5' THEN '120'
    END AS 'AccountType_id',
CASE WHEN s1.SGMTNUMB = '2' 
THEN LEFT(s1.SGMNTID, 2)
ELSE 'DEFAULT'
END AS 'AccGroupName'

 FROM GL40200 s1

UNION 

SELECT  REPLACE ([ACTNUMBR_1]+'-'+ [ACTNUMBR_2]+'-'+ [ACTNUMBR_3]+'-'+[ACTNUMBR_4]+'-'+    [ACTNUMBR_5],' ', '') AS 'AccCode',
 '' AS 'CodeDesc',
 '0' AS 'AccountType_id',
 'Default' AS 'AccGroupName'
FROM GL00100 a

INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\srahmani\verian/myfilename.txt'
```

Answer (score 21):

You do this in the SSMS app, not the SQL.

In the toolbar select:

`Query --> Results To --> Results To File`

Then Execute the SQL statements and it will prompt you to save to a text file with an .rpt extension. Open the results in a Text Editor.

Comment: So there is no way to do this on the command line if I need to set the query up as a job?

Comment: Sure, use SqlCmd or BCP.  To be fair, you asked how to do it "in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio".

Comment: That solution seems limited - you need Crystal Reports to read it.

Comment: @SteveStaple Not sure what you mean by that - it's just a text file.

Comment: You can open the file using Notepad.

Comment: I think @SteveStaple's comment is based on the fact that this generates a .rpt file (at least in SQL Server 2014 it does) - but that's not a Crystal Reports .rpt file. This answer to a related question contains more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36018426/4659442

Answer (score 11):

Another way is from command line, using the osql:

```
OSQL -S SERVERNAME -E -i thequeryfile.sql -o youroutputfile.txt
```

This can be used from a BAT file and shceduled by a windows user to authenticated.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [bcp utility](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/export-query-txt-file).

> To copy the result set from a Transact-SQL statement to a data file,
>   use the queryout option. The following example copies the result of a query into the Contacts.txt data file. The example assumes that you are using Windows Authentication and have a trusted connection to the server instance on which you are running the bcp command. At the
>   Windows command prompt, enter:

```
bcp "<your query here>" queryout Contacts.txt -c -T
```

You can use BCP by directly calling as operating sytstem command in SQL Agent job.

Answer (score 7):

You can use windows Powershell to execute a query and output it to a text file

> Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "Select * from database" -ServerInstance "Servername\SQL2008" -Database "DbName" > c:\Users\outputFileName.txt

Answer (score 0):

The BCP Utility can also be used in the form of a .bat file, but be cautious of escape sequences (ie quotes "" must be used in conjunction with ) and the appropriate tags.

.bat Example:

```
C:
bcp "\"YOUR_SERVER\".dbo.Proc" queryout C:\FilePath.txt -T -c -q
-- Add PAUSE here if you'd like to see the completed batch
```

-q MUST be used in the presence of quotations within the query itself.

BCP can also run Stored Procedures if necessary.  Again, be cautious: Temporary Tables must be created prior to execution or else you should consider using Table Variables.

Comment: Yes BCP does work in stored procedures. To get around this I use a stored procedure to collect the data in memory and then scheduler to kick off the BCP utility for the export.

Answer (score -3):

This is quite simple to do and the answer is available in other queries. For those of you who are viewing this:

```
select entries from my_entries where id='42' INTO OUTFILE 'bishwas.txt';
```

Comment: That command is probably valid in MySQL or Oracle. It is not valid in SQL Server.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Didn't know that.