# How to create a txt file composed by output from different SQL queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a txt file from a SQL SERVER DataBase composed as follows:

```
Products
OutputQuery1

Racks
OutputQuery2

Products per Rack
OutputQuery3

...
```

OutputQuery1 is only a value returned from Query1

OutputQuery2 is only a value returned from Query2

OutputQuery3:

each row is composed by the following columns: Id_Prod, Id_Rack, NumProd
in the txt file I have to show only the number of product.

This is an example:

```
Products
3
Racks
2

Products per Rack
5 5 5
4 4 4
```

Have you some suggestion??

Thnaks!

Comment: See [SQL Server : export query as a .txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620198/sql-server-export-query-as-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this multiple ways:

If you need to export a query to txt.

You can go to the ribbon on the top of SQL server and select **Results to text**

another way

Right click the top-right corner of the result set while it's in grid view. If formatting is not an issue, you can just directly **copy and paste entire contents from here**.

Right-Click top-right corner
SELECT ALL
Copy with Headers/Without
Paste to blank txt document.

You could also write an **SSIS package**.