# How To Back up Sqlsrv Database Into .sql File Using Php

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlsrv

I'm working with **sqlsrv** on php. I tried to export my database into `.sql` file but it didn't work. Can someone please help me?

i tried this,

```
$file = '/sqlsrv/backup.sql';
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$file' FROM '##table##'") or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems there is nothing like `INTO File` in MsSql. You could have a look at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620198/sql-server-export-query-as-a-txt-file) and [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189569(v=sql.105).aspx) as well