# Saving Stored Procedure result to excel or csv file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012,

I got stored procedure whose result I want to save to excel or csv file so to do so I right click on stored procedure result and paste in excel sheet or right click on 'save stored procedure result', followed by save result as 'csv' file but my issue is save data got corrupted in sense order of data in cell changes, is it because some column in result have some null value! am not sure.

I am not sure how I can correctly save result

Comment: this link could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620198/sql-server-export-query-as-a-txt-file

Comment: If the order was lost, why not just order it in excel? Seems practical, though I'm not sure what could have really happened here using the methods you mentioned. You could use bcp out too.