# How to run a script for each table and save the result into separate CSV files in SSMS 2014?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, management-studio-express

I have an SQL script that outputs these, given a table name:

- the column names in the table
- the datatypes for those columns
- the column allows `NULL` or not
- the column has unique constraint or not.

Like this:

```
column | datatype | nullable | unique
--------------------------------------
       |          |          |
       |          |          |
       |          |          |
```

Then I save the result of the script into a csv file, and run a python script to do something else with the result<sup>1</sup>. Now, what I want to do is automate the process. For about 2000 tables in the database, it is painstakingly clumsy to do the *running-sql-script* then *saving-to-csv-file* and then *running-python-script* cycle for each of those 2000 tables.

Is there any way to automate this in SSMS. I am using SSMS 2014. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538162/convert-ssms-rpt-output-file-to-txt-csv). Though that is related, that isn't actually what I want.

---

<sub>**1.** I use the python script to create a C# domain class to be used by entity framework.</sub>

Comment: You can use `BCP` (like [in this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/writing-select-result-to-a-csv-file)) to output to CSV from your query results, then just use a cursor to iterate through whichever tables you need to do this for.

Comment: You build a reusable [Integration Servies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) package.  Among others things, the package could kick-off your Python script.

Comment: @destination-data From the link you gave I came to know that that is a *SQL Server 2016 and later* feature, but I am using SQL Server 2014. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: @destination-data I am using SQL Server 2016 now, so I will give what you said a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sysobjects cursor to collect the id of the table and run bcp utility to export the results to CSV table.
Here is the script that i write for this job.

```
DECLARE @TableID int

DECLARE @TableName varchar(100)

DECLARE @sql_command varchar(4000)

DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(4000)

DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(100)  ='AdventureWorks2012'

DECLARE @SQLServerName varchar(100)  ='CEMUNEY\S12'

DECLARE Cursor_Line CURSOR FOR
SELECT id,name FROM sys.sysobjects where type='U'

OPEN Cursor_Line
FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Line INTO @TableID, @TableName


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN


    SET @sql_command = N'SELECT [column] = cols.name ,[datatype] = typeuser.name ,is_nullable ,is_identity FROM @DatabaseName.sys.columns cols INNER JOIN @DatabaseName.sys.systypes datatypes ON cols.user_type_id = datatypes.xusertype LEFT OUTER JOIN @DatabaseName.sys.systypes typeuser ON  datatypes.xtype = typeuser.xusertype where object_id =' + STR(@TableID)


    SET @sql_command = REPLACE(@sql_command,  '@DatabaseName', @DatabaseName)

    set @bulk_cmd = 'SQLCMD -S @SQLServerName -W -E -q  "set nocount on;' + @sql_command +  '" -s "," -o "D:\' +  @TableName + '.csv"'

    SET @bulk_cmd = REPLACE(@bulk_cmd,  '@SQLServerName', @SQLServerName)


    exec xp_cmdshell @bulk_cmd

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_Line INTO @TableID, @TableName


END

CLOSE Cursor_Line
DEALLOCATE Cursor_Line
```